# Apart from trivial data types, then are python immutable object ids the same?

Tags: python, optimization, immutability, inequality

For immutable data types, Python does not guarantee that two constructions result in two different objects; as such, `1+1 is 2` may or may not return `True`.  For sure, *mutable* types *do* result in separate objects: `[] is []` will always return `False`.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types:

> Types affect almost all aspects of object behavior. Even the importance of object identity is affected in some sense: for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while for mutable objects this is not allowed. E.g., after a = 1; b = 1, **a and b may or may not refer to the same object with the value one**, depending on the implementation, but after c = []; d = [], c and d are guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty lists. (Note that c = d = [] assigns the same object to both c and d.)

```
>>> "abc" is "abc"
True
>>> [] is []
False
>>> 1 + 1 is 2
True
```

Now, apart from the trivial types `int`, `float`, `bool`, `string`, I would expect `tuple` and `frozenset` to show the same behavior.

But I find no cases where they do:

```
>>> {1, 2} is {1, 2}
False
>>> (1, ) is (1, )
False
```

Are there any implementation s that do yield the same id for separate immutable objects?

Comment: To my surprise, I found `tuple() is tuple()` to be True (on cpython 3.7).

Comment: The string and integers results are due to python interning those objects, not their immutability

Comment: @rdas: exactly: python is allowed to intern them for _immutable_ types.  My question is: when does it actually happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the `is` equality for these objects are resultant from interpreter tricks (that are not apart of the language spec AFAIK but consequences of CPython)

For example ([with `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)).

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behavior of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

And for strings, python does [`interning`](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/). `bool` is a subclass of `int` (`issubclass(bool, int)`) which explains shared `id` for `bool`s. AFAIK, floats (aside from literals in 3.8) never return True for `is` equality.

---

In python3.8, `(1,) is (1,)` is [actually](https://bugs.python.org/issue34850) `True` due to changes in literal evaluation.

```
>>> (1,) is (1,)
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
True
```

Along with a warning for `is` being used for literals. However, assigning variables and performing the comparison is False (as expected).

Note that `tuple() is tuple()` and `frozenset() is frozenset()` both return True. However, their mutable counterparts (`list` and `set`) do not have this property.

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, `list` and `set` are _mutable_ collections, and they explicitly _must not_ have this property.